# Exclusive Chat session?

Tags: discussion, site-definition, chat

Please let me know your thoughts on arranging an exclusive chat session  for dbas (dba.stackexchange.com users) to discuss site progress, faq page, tag-wikis and site promotion?

EDIT:

Chat Session Scheduled to 30<sup>th</sup> April 2011 on 10.00 UTC just before [Happy Hours](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/89/the-tavern-general?tab=schedule)

[Exclusive chat session for dba users to discuss site progress, faq page, tag-wikis and site promotion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/179/database-administrators?tab=schedule)

Please register yourself...

Comment: Please suggest suitable date and time to schedule this chat event.

Comment: Any time/date set for the chat event?

Comment: @Sathya - no... I expected lots of activities to this post. What about 10:00 PM UTC for 1h just before "The Tavern"?

Comment: @Sandy do you mean before [Happy Hours](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/89/the-tavern-general?tab=schedule)?

Comment: @Sathya - Yes. Hope it will be suitable time for most of us.

Comment: @Sandy cool - I should be around

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot be there for this chat. However, I would like to say this: I hope that this StackExchange Site comes out beta and continues. It is collectively up to us to promote the use of this site. Easily we could ask on the MetaSites of StackOverflow, ServerFault, and SuperUser for those users to route DB Specific Questions to DBA. If this chat results in additional suggestions and avenue of promotions, I am all ears !!!

Answer (score 2):

I'm all for this. Of course, I've been a big proponent of wanting to use the chat more myself anyways ;)

I think the site would do well to have more users participating in chat, as that would reinforce the participation in the chat and in the site ;)

Comment: Yay! Please suggest a suitable time to schedule this chat event.

Comment: A weekend seems like it would be better able to accommodate more people. However, I know that you're on a timezone that's almost opposite mine (not quite) so if we wanted to do several we could do that. Have them spaced 8 hours apart or something?

Answer (score 2):

You will definitely want to use the "site message" banner to let people know about this event -- which is actually automated so long as a diamond mod has properly scheduled the event in chat.

Comment: Sure! I've added one...

Comment: It might be better to wait until you had a date/time to announce it.

Comment: @sandy make sure you schedule it in the chatroom via the "schedule" tab -- http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/179/database-administrators?tab=schedule

Answer (score 1):

For those of us who couldn't attend the chat session, what was the outcome?  Any good suggestions on promoting site and helping it grow would be appreciated...

Comment: it doesn't turned out good. I guess the scheduled time wasn't suitable for most of users. Hope we can schedule another one soon.

Comment: can you suggest a better time to meet?

Comment: Not sure, I'm in the UK so I'm frequently out of sync with the rest of you guys...  I guess the questions should be in order: 1) Who wants to do  a chat session on site status?  2) Where are people located (time zone wise)? 3) Agree time...